# JSON Request Error 500

Tags: php, javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

I'm wanting to populate a select textbox with some dynamic data from another page. The page outputs a php array using json_encode. This is working fine for me on another page on the same site but for some reason the console in chrome and firebug say "500 (Internal Server Error)". If I browse to the page myself I can see the output fine, I've made sure the URL's correct as I opened the link that JSON failed to access.
My request is:

```
var Type = $("#a option:selected").text();
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    dateChangeRequest=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    dateChangeRequest=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
dateChangeRequest.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (dateChangeRequest.readyState==4 && dateChangeRequest.status==200)
        {
        var returnList = dateChangeRequest.responseText;
        }
    }
dateChangeRequest.open("GET","entList.php?ents="+Type,true);
dateChangeRequest.send();
```

Some example data from the dynamic page:

```
[{"EntID":2,"Display":"Some Name - Alias"},{"EntID":3,"Display":"Some Other Name - Another Alias"}]
```

I'm not sure if it means anything, but on the pages that are working firebug reports:

```
Connection  Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive  timeout=15, max=90
```

But on this page it reports:

```
Connection  close
```

even though the request header asks for keep-alive.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Actually, when I just put that example data on the page it's fetched fine. I'm generating the array of data from a database and then outputting with json_encode, which is working fine for another page. Here is an excerpt from the actual output of the page:

```
[{"EntID":2,"Display":"Eddard Stark - Ned"},{"EntID":3,"Display":"Robb Stark - The Young Wolf"},{"EntID":5,"Display":"Catelyn Tully - Cat"},{"EntID":7,"Display":"Aegon I Targaryen - Aegon the Conqueror"},{"EntID":20,"Display":"Rhaenyra Targaryen - "},{"EntID":11,"Display":"Aenys I Targaryen - "},{"EntID":12,"Display":"Maegor I Targaryen - "},{"EntID":13,"Display":"Jaehaerys I Targaryen - "},{"EntID":14,"Display":"Viserys I Targaryen - "},{"EntID":15,"Display":"Aegon II Targaryen - "},{"EntID":16,"Display":"Rhaenys Targaryen - "},{"EntID":17,"Display":"Visenya Targaryen - "},{"EntID":74,"Display":"Jon Snow - Lord Snow"}]
```

Some more info:
It works fine when the data is static, i.e. I copy and paste the whole array onto the page as text and comment out all the data.
I can actually see the response text in the chrome console, even though the server says Error 500.
I have just tried echoing the structure of the array myself instead of json_encode and that doesn't work either.

Comment: I look at your code that you are using jquery `var Type = $("#a option:selected").text();`. So, why you didn't use it. It will more simple.

Comment: I actually did to start with, but I hadn't used it before like I had this version. It, too, threw the 500 error so I reverted back to this method that I *knew* works.

Comment: Pretty sure. When I browser to the page with any possible url parameter I get an array of data as in the post. The array is much longer than the example provided though. At first I thought it might be because the ID's were getting quotes round them but JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK changed that but I still have the 500 error.

Comment: You have jQuery available so why not use `$.ajax()`?!

Comment: I explained that in a previous comment. I have just updated my question with more information.

Comment: The 500 Internal Server Error is a very general HTTP status code that means something has gone wrong on the web site's server but the server could not be more specific on what the exact problem is.

Comment: Can you show me, http request that make 500 error appear?

Comment: The error is thrown on `dateChangeRequest.send();`. All the request code is included in the question above.

Comment: Ok, It had nothing to do with the array or anything like that. It was the way in which I closed the connection to the database...

Answer (score 0):

It could be a bug on your PHP page. Do you have error reporting on? You might find your answer there.

Try viewing the error log on your server using

```
tail -f /var/log/apache/php.errors
```

Seeing as you don't have command line access add

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

To the top of your .php file.

Comment: Where would I put that command? I don't have any command line access that I'm aware of.

Comment: There are no errors showing anywhere. The page containing the data is still outputting the correct array and the page I want to display it on has no errors either. I put that line at the top of both pages.